How do I pass varying length sequence input to decoder for look ahead mask?
I am working on a translation model by transformer from scratch for the first time. And I am encountering problems while training decoders with varying sequence lengths with look ahead pads. I am unable to understand how to integrate varying length input with batch size and pass it to a custom training loop. How can I solve this?
def create_padding_mask(seq):
    seq = tf.cast(tf.math.equal(seq, 0), tf.float32)
    return seq[:, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis, :]

def create_look_ahead_mask(size):
    mask = 1 - tf.linalg.band_part(tf.ones((size, size)), -1, 0)
    return mask

def CreateMask(encoderInput, decoderInput):
    encPadMask = create_padding_mask(encoderInput)
    decPadMask = create_padding_mask(decoderInput)
    LAMask = create_look_ahead_mask(tf.shape(decoderInput)[1])
    # decTargetPadMask = create_padding_mask(decoderInput)
    LAMask = tf.maximum(decPadMask, LAMask)
    return encPadMask, LAMask, decPadMask

